# 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples django 3.1

Tags: django

whene i want to makemigration it show me this error

```
user.User.allowd_to_take_appointement: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
user.User.type_of_user: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

this is my models.py

```
class TypeOfUser(models.TextChoices):
    PATIENT = 'patient', 'Patient'
    DOCTOR = 'doctor', 'Doctor'
    RECEPTION = 'reception', 'Reception'
    TEMPORARY = 'temporary', 'Temporary'

class AllowdToTakeAppointement(models.TextChoices):
    YES = ('yes', 'Yes')
    NO = ('no', 'No')

class User(AbstractUser):
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=TypeOfUser, default=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=AllowdToTakeAppointement, default=AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES)

    def is_doctor(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.DOCTOR

    def can_add_appointment(self):
        return self.type_of_user == AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES
```

i'm using django 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `choices=…` should be provided the outcome of the `.choices` property of your `TypeOfUser` and `AllowdToTakeAppointment`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    type_of_user = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        #            .choices ↓
        choices=TypeOfUser.choices,
        default=TypeOfUser.PATIENT
    )
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        #                          .choices ↓
        choices=AllowdToTakeAppointement.choices,
        default=AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES
    )

    def is_doctor(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.DOCTOR

    def can_add_appointment(self):
        return self.type_of_user == AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES
```